# I'm in a beginner's Python course, and my assignment is to print variable 'N' backwards using a 'while' statement

Tags: python, codio

Here are my instructions:

We will pass you a value, N. You should output every positive value from N down to and including 0.

And here is my assignment:

```
    # Get N from the command line
    import sys
    N = int(sys.argv[1])

    # Your code goes here
    counter = 0 
    while counter <= N:
     print(counter-N)
     counter = counter + 1
```

My solution prints this:

```
Program Output

Program Failed for Input: 3
Expected Output: 3
2
1
0
Your Program Output: -3
-2
-1
0
```

As you can see, I got the output to show -3, -2, -1, 0, but it should be 3, 2, 1, 0. Please be mindful that I am a beginner, and my code must pass using a 'while' statement, and my code must be inputted in Codio. Thank you in advance for any assistance rendered.

Comment: So `print(N-counter)` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Since we are expecting N's value to be higher than counter's value, counter-N will be negative.

Try the following:

```
 import sys
    N = int(sys.argv[1])

    # Your code goes here
    counter = 0 
    while counter <= N:
     print(N-counter)
     counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: Thanks bee it worked. I really appreciate this community because being a student, you don't get much help, and I know the objective is to learn, but if I can't figure something out after a few days, what am I supposed to do? Anyway thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just step down from N to 0:

```
# Get N from the command line
import sys
N = int(sys.argv[1])

# Your code goes here
counter = N
while counter >= 0:
 print(counter)
 counter -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `counter-N` to the `abs` function:

```
while counter <= N:
  print(abs(counter-N))
  counter = counter + 1
```

Or, just use `N-counter`:

```
while counter <= N:
 print(N-counter)
 counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: why do you use abs?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ seeing as the OP is a programming beginner, it makes sense to provide simple workarounds that are more mathematically understandable such as the absolute value rather than tweaking the counter.

Comment: I hardly think introducing a new function is "mathematically simpler" to just reversing the order of operands to get rid of the negative sign. ...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I believe that in this case, the absolute value is more intuitive, whereas `N-counter` is more advanced.

Comment: N is (presumably) a positive value. `counter` starts from 0 and goes up to N. So it would "intuitively" make sense to subtract the smaller number from the larger.